# Getting NPM module not found for a local dependency outside my folder

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, package.json

I have a project that look like this:

```
|-- client
|   |-- index.js
|   |-- ...
|   |-- package.json
|   └-- webpack.config.json
|-- lib
|   └-- myLocalLibrary
|       |-- index.js
|       └-- package.json
└-- server
    └-- ...
```

Code from `lib` is used in both `client` and `server` by importing libraries with npm

So `client/package.json` and `server/package.json` contain:

```
{
  dependencies: {
    ...
    myLocalLibrary: 'file: ../lib/myLocalLibrary',
    ...
  } 
}
```

The problem is: when I run webpack in the client, it fails to resolve the imports used in `myLocalLibrary`, because:

a) NPM installs subdependencies for the local library in `client/node_modules`, not in `lib/myLocalLibrary/node_modules`

b) Webpack resolved code for `myLocalLibrary` using its source folder, which is out of the reach of `client/node_modules`

What should I do in a case like this?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using webpack as a build tool, I think you have to use `resolve.alias` webpack config. We don't need `node_modules` in production env if we have use webpack to concat all files to one `entry` file.
In your webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      myLocalLibrary: path.resolve(__dirname, 'lib/myLocalLibrary'), // where is the webpack.config.json?
    }
  }
};
```

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/

Comment: True, we don't need node_modules in production, but when webpack tries to resolve an import (let's say `moment`) from the `lib/myLocalLibrary` folder, can't find any, because from that folder's point of view, `moment` is not installed. I don't see how using an alias would make any difference.

Comment: @javorosas Try turn off symlink resolution in webpack via `resolve: { symlinks: false }`

Comment: yeah, that worked. Could you please give me a hint on why? and what side effects could such option cause?

Comment: Ok, I'm seeing that only solved the client part of the problem. I'm still getting the same error in code executed by Node.js in the `server` folder.